# View with two filter groups using "OR" not aggregating correctly

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that I need to count the number of items currently unread. It is a list that combines slightly different entities on slightly different conditions, so I have two filter groups(using OR) on my view to select all content appropriately. This works well except for the aggregation of the results. When I set the view to aggregate by counting a nid field, it doesn't aggregate the results. Instead, it simply converts each nid result to display as "1".

Where is my attempt to aggregate this view going wrong?

My filters:
[image]
My Results:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was actually quite simple, and the source of error was misunderstood.

The filter groups were NOT the issue at all, but rather that there were excluded fields in the view which were not set to "count" under their aggregation settings. This broke the count. If you are having this issue, make sure all fields in your aggregation view are set to "count".